# PHP shell_exec won't work with gnome

Tags: php, bash, gnome, shell-exec

In a terminal window running `alert 9` gives me a popup saying `9`

However, running `alert 9` in `shell_exec` gives nothing.

---

What should I be aware of?

*Just to mention: other commands work neither that interact with the GUI. I am using gnome 3.16.3*

---

**UPDATE**

My concrete goal is to run an [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) command using the gnome environment. ( `xdotool key ctrl+shift+u` )

Comment: @SteJ You mean `$DISPLAY`.

Comment: WHOOPS! Yes, I do indeed mean `$DISPLAY` -- sorry

Comment: I would suggest that PHP is not aware of your X11 environment. Try setting the $DISPLAY environment variable in your script?

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution. How could I deploy this method properly?

Comment: Update on bounty description based on @Halayem Anis's answer: the answer does not have to neccessarily use the concrete command `alert 9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert` is not a command, but an alias for `notify-send`. Aliases are loaded only in interactive shell, so it is not the best choice to test `shel_exec`.

These 2 command work well with php-cli:

```
$ php -r "shell_exec('notify-send 9');"
$ php -r "shell_exec('xdotool key ctrl+shift+u');"
```

The first one pops the 9 in notification area, and the last one output underscored 'u'.

Apache with mod_php is a daemon, subprocess of `init`, which knows nothing about xserver. If, for example, you run php built-in web server from a terminal **within** xserver like `$ php -S 0:8080` it works as expected.

Comment: Both of them work great inside a terminal inside the gnome environment. However, from the LAMP, they still fail to interact with the GUI.

Comment: If LAMP is apache with mod_php, it is a daemon, subprocess of `init`, which knows nothing about xserver. If, for example, you run php built-in web server from a terminal **within** xserver like `$ php -S 0:8080` it will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`alert` is not a standard command, at least on **RedHat**, **Solaris** and **AIX**, so you have to mention it in your question that it's a proprietary command/program

Your `alert` script/program does'nt consider to flush text data in standard or file output, so you can't do any redirection using pipe **|**, or redirect **>**,  and finally, the php function `shell_exec()` can catch anything

Maybe you can redirect graphic data (i'm not sure) but generally, it's used by the graphic server

Comment: Thank You, your info was valuable. Please, see my update on the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe PHP is launching a shell that isn't aware of your X11 environment and you need to set the `$DISPLAY` environment variable. Try the following modification to your shell_exec:

```
shell_exec("DISPLAY=\":0\" alert 9");
```

Comment: Great answer. However, running this command also yields nothing from shell_exec. It works when executing manually through gnome-terminal btw.

Comment: Is your PHP script running as the same user you logged in and started X with? Your X session will only be authorised for your user; you can use the `xauth` command to authorise other users and hosts, but this can be a real pain to get working. Do you get any errors returned from shell_exec?

Comment: I get absolutely no output, no errors. I am `www-data` if I ask `whoami` from shell_exec. However, I can switch to my user using `sudo -u myuser whoami` ( -> `myuser` )

Is this a way to go?

Comment: Yes, wwwdata won't have access to your X server. I wouldn't generally recommend using sudo commands from within a php script as this is a vulnerability waiting to happen, but if the script is just for you and isn't going to be publically available then it will at least prove that this is indeed the problem. Ultimately the answer would be to add www-data to your xauth; it's been a long while since I've done this though so  I'm a bit hazy on the details. [Manpage is here](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.7.0/doc/xauth.1.html)

Comment: Another way to test this theory would be to log in to your x session as www-data **but this is not recommended** - www-data is usually configured without a password specifically to prevent users from logging in as this user.

Comment: Just a final tuppence to say: It's generally inadvisible to allow PHP scripts running on a web server to have access to X directly (otherwise an attacker could be launching any app they like) - It may be better to have a separate program to produce the alerts for you, and then communicate between your PHP script and this program using some form of IPC such as sockets, pipes or even just simple file-based message queues.

Comment: It is for personal usage inside well nested environment, so security is not a question. How could I make `www-data` reach my X server?

Comment: I'm currently on a Windows system at work, so I can't test an xauth and xdm solution for you right now - take a look at using `xauth` to get things working, then look into modifying your `xdm` configuration to make the authorisation permanent. You could also run a second X server as www-data; there is a way to run an x-server within a window on your gnome desktop, but for the life of me I can't remember what the command is.